# Favicon not working for app served by nginx that is deployed in Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, yaml, nginx-config

We are having an issue getting our favicon to show up. Little background on the app setup. The application is a React app that is served up by Nginx. We did have to make a change to the default.conf file to add a location block to for an alias with the path to the favicon to get it working in Docker. So, from Docker the favicon now shows up just fine when ran locally, but when deployed to our K8s the favicon no longer shows up. I did test with private mode/incognito to make sure it wasn't a caching issue.

Favicon is located in the root of the app along side the index.html.

I haven't been able to find anything that has really helped with resolving this issue, but I do believe I need to reference either the nginx's conf file or the favicon in the deployment yaml.

Has anyone ever dealt with something similar to this before or have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out for this scenario. Since the browser tab was opened by another application, it was the path to that apps favicon I needed. For some reason it was trying to look in that folders directories. Doesn't make a lot of sense why it would to me but it is better to have one source.